# A problem on connectedness

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $Y$ is a subspace of the topological space $X$ and $A$ is a subset of $Y$. If $A$ is connected in $X$, then does it follow that $A$ is connected in $Y$ as well? What about the other way round?

Comment: Do you mean connected or path-connected?

Comment: I meant connected......

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 4):

A subset $A$ of a topological space $X$ is connected if and only if every continuous map $f\colon A\to \{0,1\}$ (the codomain is endowed with the discrete topology) is constant.

This is independent on what space $A$ is embedded in.

It is similar for the case when $A$ is path-connected: $A$ is path-connected if and only if, for every $a,b\in A$, there exists a continuous map $f\colon[0,1]\to A$ such that $f(0)=a$ and $f(1)=b$. Again, this is independent on what topological space $A$ is embedded in.

Comment: What you are saying is path-connected, slightly different from connected

Comment: @yujie...I meant connected..but thanks...@egreg cleared my doubt

Comment: @YujieZha No, path-connected is characterized in a very different fashion. But I added the argument for that case.

Comment: @egreg yea, I noticed that the definition is different. Sorry, did not read closely. (+1)

Comment: Very nice. ..............